# VARBINARY(SQLSERVER) to RAW(ORACLE) via CSV created using SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle11g, sqlcmd, sql-loader, varbinary

I am trying to export JBPM tables from SQLSERVER in CSV file using **SQLCMD** and I wish to import it to ORACLE DB. Table structures as follows:

**SOURCE table columns(SQLSERVER) :**

```
[PROCESSFILE_] [numeric](19, 0) ,
[BYTES_] [varbinary](1024) ,
[INDEX_] [int]
```

**TARGET table columns (ORACLE) :**

```
[PROCESSFILE_] NUMBER(19,0) , 
[BYTES_] RAW(1024), 
[INDEX_] NUMBER(10,0)
```

I am using **SQLLDR** to load the data into ORACLE and I'm getting following error:

```
Record 53: Rejected - Error on table JBPM_BYTEBLOCK_TEST, column BYTES_.
Field in data file exceeds maximum length
```

My controlfile looks something like this:

```
load data
    infile 'JBPM_BYTEBLOCK.csv'
           into table JBPM_BYTEBLOCK_TEST
fields terminated by ","
(PROCESSFILE_, BYTES_ ,INDEX_)
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this and get the hex data imported to oracle? Is it even possible through CSV?

Since I'm new to this i'd also like to know is there any better approach than CSV?

**Note:** *My target DB is on AWS and we have connectivity issues between the two databases.*